# Question about the net force a rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

In a case like this one where the mass of the rope is considered to be 0 how can we prove that the net force on the rope is 0?
Using $F=ma$ I don't see how that would prove that the net force is 0.

Is the mass of the objects considered to be a force applied on the rope? If yes then the net force is not 0.

Is it just that $F=ma$ doesn't work on massless objects?

Comment: the rope length is constant . thus $~T_1=T_2~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a case like this one where the mass of the rope is considered to be 0 how can we prove that the net force on the rope is 0? Using F=ma I don't see how that would prove that the net force is 0

The acceleration is some finite $\vec a$ so $\vec F=m\vec a=0\vec a=0$

> Is the mass of the objects considered to be a force applied on the rope?

No, mass is mass and force is force. Mass is not force.

The weight of the masses ($m\vec g$) is a force. But that force is applied to the masses, not to the rope. The only forces acting on the rope are the contact forces between the rope and the masses and the pulley.

There are three forces acting on the rope. Two tension forces pulling down, one from each mass, and one contact force pulling up from the pulley. The downward tension forces are determined by the kinematics, and the upward force from the pulley is whatever it needs to be to make the net force 0.

So the net force on a massless object is always 0. But that doesn't tell you about the acceleration because $\vec F = m \vec a \rightarrow 0 = 0 \vec a$ is satisfied for any finite $\vec a$. So you have to determine the acceleration of a massless object from some constraints rather than from Newton's 2nd law. In this case the constraints are that it is inextensible and that its ends are attached to the blocks.

> Is it just that F=ma doesn't work on massless objects?

It works, it just isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Solution,
If the net force on body is zero then T1 = T2 = T
Mass (M1) = 8kg
Mass (M2) = 5kg
Acceleration due to gravity (g) = 10 m/s^2
Mass M1 will go in downward direction,
The resultant force here is given by,
Resultant force = M1*g - T
M1*a = M1*g - T
8*a = 8*10 -T
8a = 80 - T __(I)

Mass M2 will go in upward direction, here the resultant force is,
Resultant force = T2 - M2*g
M2*a = T2 - M2*g
5*a = T2 - 5*10
5a = T - 50 __(II)

From equation I and II,
5a + 50 = 80 - 8a
13 a = 30
a = 2.31 m/s^2 is your required acceleration.

Actually to be more precise more than mass the weight of the object is providing the tension in the string and the required force applied in the body.